# Finding a variable when only 1 asymptote is allowed

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Consider the function
$$f(x)=\frac{x^2-1}{x^2-ax+a+1}.$$

What are the values of a such that there is only one asymptote.  I am getting $a = -1$, but a friend got something different. What is the answer here?

Comment: Please type your equation up using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Using a graphing tool like [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6njmajf6cr) shows that you are correct.

Comment: In addition, do you want values of $a$ such that there is only one asymptote, or only one vertical asymptote?

Comment: one vertical asymptote

Answer (score 0):

From the degrees of the numerator and denominator, we know there will be a horizontal asymptote. As such, you are looking for values for $a$ such that the denominator does not produce any vertical asymptotes.

To make that happen, we can create the quadratic denominator such that it has no real roots. Using the discriminant of the quadratic equation and setting it to be negative, we can solve the inequality for $a$.

$$(-a)^2-4(1)(a+1)<0$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Since we want exactly one value where the denominator is $0$, which will create exactly one asymptote, set the discriminant to $0$:

$$b^2-4ac = 0$$
$$(-a)^2-4(1)(a+1)= 0 $$
$$a^2-4a-4=0$$

However, you also need to check that neither $x-1$ nor $x+1$ is a factor of the denominator. So using the factor theorem, we need to find $a$:

$$(1)^2-a(1)+a+1 = 0 \Rightarrow 2 = 0 $$
$$(-1)^2-a(-1)+a+1 = 0 \Rightarrow 2a+2=0, a=-1$$

This is where your solution comes from.

Therefore there are three values of $a$ that produce only $1$ asymptote.